# Best practise to store Team/Subscription information using OAuth2

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token

What is the best practise to identify the team/subscription or group of a user? 
Can/should it be stored as a Claim within the JWT token or should this kind of information never be part of a users identity but part of a policy check within the resource a user tries to access?

Comment: I think you will find both is common. Often it is provided as part of the OpenID Connect userinfo_endpoint and/or as a claim in the access_token. Provide some more details as to your context.

Comment: So I'm using an authentication server (IdentityServer4) and have various clients (web, mobile, desktop). 
Each user is part of at least one team. Ideally once a user is authenticated he should be able (authorized) to access only his team information he signed in to. Eventually I'd like to introduce a dashboard that pulls information from all teams. Would I keep in that case an array of team_ids as a claim and then in addition a current_team claim to indicate into which team the user signed in?